# SFTP path format versus local path format

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I'm writing some Java code (using JSch library) to SFTP into a remote Windows machine and copy a file to my local Windows folder.

When specifying the path to the file on the remote machine, I'm forced to specify the path in the format `/C/temp/myfile.txt` instead of `C:\temp\myfile.txt`.

Questions:

1. Could you tell me what this format is? Is there a name for it?
2. Could you tell me if it's possible to use any other format for the path? I'd like to be able to specify the path as `C:\temp\myfile.txt`, so it's not apparent to the users whether the file is being SFTP'd from a remote machine at all. I'm guessing I'd have to parse/split/replace characters in the path as the FTP get command wouldn't understand this path format.

thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SFTP protocol mandates that `/` must be used as a path separator.

See [SFTP specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-13):

> This protocol represents file names as strings.  File names are
> assumed to use the slash ('/') character as a directory separator.
>
> File names starting with a slash are "absolute", and are relative to
> the root of the file system.  Names starting with any other character
> are relative to the user's default directory (home directory).  Note
> that identifying the user is assumed to take place outside of this
> protocol.

---

It's the SFTP server that maps real OS-specific paths on the server's file system to a syntax, that conforms to SFTP specification.

You have to use the syntax, that the server's authors have chosen to use.

So in all cases you have to map the `\` to `/`.

And you may need to remove the `:`. Though that can actually be configurable. Many (particularly Windows) SFTP servers have a configuration, that allows you to map a virtual SFTP path to a real path. In that case, you may be able to map `/C:/` to `C:\`.

*In any case, your question is actually not about JSch, let alone Java, but about your SFTP server.*

See also FAQ for *my* WinSCP SFTP client: [How do I change drive on the remote panel?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_remote_drive)