# Transferring SFTP files using Paramiko fail with "FileNotFound: [Errno 2] No such file"

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I am trying to put together an SFTP module for use with a drone in a project for school. Security is not a concern for me right now, as I am simply trying to get successful connections and file transfers established first.

```
import paramiko

#Open Transport
host, port = "IP Address", 22
transport = paramiko.Transport((host,port))

#Authentication
username, password = "Username", "Password"
transport.connect(None, username, password)

#Connect
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)

#Download
remotePath = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Upload Data\\Test.txt"
localPath = "C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\Test.txt"
sftp.get(remotePath, localPath)

#Upload
remotePath = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Upload Data"
localPath = "C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\Test.txt"
sftp.put(localPath, remotePath)

#Close
if sftp: sftp.close()
if transport: transport.close()
```

When running the above code, I get `FileNotFound: [Errno 2] No such file` returned. The same error is returned for attempted uploads. I am hosting the SFTP server on a Windows platform using OpenSSH, as the paths may suggest.

The `sshd_config` file is pointing correctly to the path defined in `remotePath`. Firewall rules on the server are correctly configured, as I am able to connect to the SFTP server using FileZilla from the same computer I am attempting to connect to the server from using Python. I can ping the remote server using the same machine as well. As far as I can tell, this is not a connectivity issue between the server and client.

I'm really not sure what I am doing wrong. I have quadruple checked the paths in my code are correct. I have been knee-deep in tabs for the past couple of hours trying to troubleshoot, but I'm running out of ideas and so I need to ask the internet.

Answer (score 0):

The `C:\Users\User\Desktop\Upload Data\Test.txt` is not what a typical SFTP path looks like. It rather looks like a physical path on the server.

Login with GUI SFTP client and see what is the actual SFTP path to your files.

If could be like (or any other):

- `/Upload Data/Test.txt`
- `/C/Users/User/Desktop/Upload Data/Test.txt`
- `/Test.txt`

See also [SFTP path format versus local path format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45691471/850848).

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not use `Transport` class directly this way – You are bypassing a host key check and consequently losing a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack). Instead use `SSHClient` class. See also [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883)*.