# Python OSError: Failure with SFTP

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko, pysftp

I'm testing SFTP communication on a Windows 11 laptop with SFTP server running at localhost:3373. An `sftp.get` request generates an *"OSError: Failure"* error with this code:

```
import pysftp

remotepath = "C:/Users/Profile/sftpdata/remote/gimme.txt"
localpath = "C:/Users/Profile/sftpdata/local/gimme.txt"

cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None
with pysftp.Connection('localhost', port=3373, username='admin', password='admin', cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    sftp.get(remotepath, localpath=localpath)
```

The traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Profile\sftpsrc\test_sftp.py", line 9, in <module>
    sftp.get(remotepath, localpath=localpath)
  File "C:\Users\Profile\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py", line 249, in get
    self._sftp.get(remotepath, localpath, callback=callback)
  File "C:\Users\Profile\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 811, in get
    size = self.getfo(remotepath, fl, callback, prefetch)
  File "C:\Users\Profile\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 782, in getfo
    file_size = self.stat(remotepath).st_size
  File "C:\Users\Profile\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 493, in stat
    t, msg = self._request(CMD_STAT, path)
  File "C:\Users\Profile\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 822, in _request
    return self._read_response(num)
  File "C:\Users\Profile\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 874, in _read_response
    self._convert_status(msg)
  File "C:\Users\Profile\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 907, in _convert_status
    raise IOError(text)
OSError: Failure
```

The environment is Windows 11, Python, Paramiko 3.0.0, sftpserver and pysftp.

The file `gimme.txt` is definitely in the remote folder. Have tried transforming the path statements using `Path` + `as_posix()` and `realpath` but with no luck. The generated key is `rsa-ssh 4096`.

Btw, `localpath = "C:/Users/Profile/sftpdata/local"` gives a Permission Error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `C:/Users/Profile/sftpdata/remote/gimme.txt` is not what a typical SFTP path looks like. It rather looks like a physical path on the server.

Login with a GUI SFTP client and see what is the actual SFTP path to your file.

It could be like (or any other):

- `/sftpdata/remote/gimme.txt`
- `/C/Users/Profile/sftpdata/remote/gimme.txt`
- `/gimme.txt`

See also [SFTP path format versus local path format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45691471/850848).

---

*Side note: you should not use pysftp. It's a dead project. Use Paramiko. See [pysftp vs. Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48434941/850848)*.

*If you want to keep using pysftp, at least do not set `cnopts.hostkeys = None`, unless you do not care about security. For the correct solution see [Verify host key with pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38939454/850848)*.